# How to solve a system of XOR equations?

Tags: linear-algebra, boolean-algebra

When I'm trying to solve this system of equations:

$$\begin{aligned} k_1 \oplus k_2 =  a \end{aligned}$$
$$\begin{aligned} k_2 \oplus k_3 =  b \end{aligned}$$
$$\begin{aligned} k_3 \oplus k_1 =  c \end{aligned}$$

I don't get any adequate result, except like $\begin{aligned} a \oplus c =  b \end{aligned}$. I can't solve this system. But when I try to solve a similar system with more unknowns:

$$\begin{aligned} k_1 \oplus k_2 \oplus k_3 =  a \end{aligned}$$
$$\begin{aligned} k_2 \oplus k_3 \oplus k_4 =  b \end{aligned}$$
$$\begin{aligned} k_3 \oplus k_4 \oplus k_1 =  c \end{aligned}$$
$$\begin{aligned} k_4 \oplus k_1 \oplus k_2 =  d \end{aligned}$$

I do get a solution:

$$\begin{aligned} k_1 = a \oplus c \oplus d \end{aligned}$$
$$\begin{aligned} k_2 = a \oplus b \oplus d \end{aligned}$$
$$\begin{aligned} k_3 = a \oplus b \oplus c \end{aligned}$$
$$\begin{aligned} k_4 = b \oplus c \oplus d \end{aligned}$$

How do I solve the first system? Is it even possible?

Comment: Solving these systems can be done with linear algebra over $\mathbb{F}_2$. The standard techniques of row reduction or Gaussian elimination will work.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: XOR is equivalent to addition in $GF(2)$.

Answer (score 1):

We need $$a \oplus c = b$$ for consistency.

Once you check that it is consistent, choose $k_2$ to be anything and you can recover $k_1$ and $k_3$.
$$k_1 = a \oplus k_2$$
$$k_3 = b \oplus k_2$$